# Can i use @JoinColumn on @OneToMany?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a "branche" that have many "categories" :

```
    @JsonProperty
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        )
    @JoinColumn(name="categorie_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Collection<Categorie> categorie=new ArrayList<>();
```

```
    @JsonProperty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="branche_id")
    private Branche branche;
```

I want to list the categories with the branche associated ! this works fine but i think its not written well.
I don't want to use mapped By on the @OneToMany , when i use it , my list of categories does no longer contain the "branche" associated .

Comment: *Can i use @JoinColumn on @OneToMany?* Yes, you can

Comment: I can see no `mapped by` here anywhere - probably missues

Comment: with these foreign-keys ? @Antoniossss

Comment: Rather not - you should have only 1 foreigh key in 1 to X relations (or your model is a mess) Are you sure it shouldn't be many-many?

Comment: yes its One To Many @Antoniossss

Comment: if category can have only 1 branch than ok - and you should have only 1 foreig key (even for bi-directional relation)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it like this

```
@JsonProperty
@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "branche"
    )
private Collection<Categorie> categorie=new ArrayList<>();
```

And

```
  @JsonProperty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categorie_id")
    private Branche branche;
```

assuming that you have model that in which every branch can have only 1 shared category (and branch should contain id of category in `category_id` column)

Comment: But i want to display the branche when i display my categories list !

Comment: i tried it and i added JsonBackReference on ManyToOne and  JsonManagedReference on OneToMany,but  It still displays the categories on the branche !

Comment: categorie**s**? It should be only 1 category there.

Comment: yes each branche have a lot of categories, sho when i try this ,and i call branches, it displays the branche and  its categories, what i want is that when i call categories, is to diplay them with the branche asociated to each categorie. when i reverse the JsonBackReference with  JsonManagedReference it works, but i think they should not be reversed, JsonBackReference should be on @ManyToOne and  JsonManagedReference on OneToMany.

Comment: if branch have multiple categories, and those categories can be attached to multiple branches, than its many-many.

Comment: no each categorie have one branche, for ex : categorie 1-branche 1 ; categorie 2 -branche1 ; categorie 3-branche-2 ; categorie 4 - branche 3 ; categorie 5 - branche 3

Comment: @LamyaeLac Use `@JsonIdentityInfo` https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338702/4207306